# Usercontrol doesnt support Webmethod?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to call a Scriptmanager webmethod in usercontrol. But Webusercontrol does not support WebMethod. Can it be achieved by Jquery Ajax or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put that web method in your page's code behind class of the user control code.

For details take a look at this article https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131232/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031704-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would put your web methods in web service.asmx file as it is easier to manage that way.

Comment: oops yes just been doing something with ashx so wrote the wrong thing down :)